# How to completely reset Ubuntu and all installed applications to its original setting?

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, reset

I have been using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS for some time now. I need to reset it to original state without reinstalling my Ubuntu. Is it possible??

Answer (score -1):

Try below command that would reconfigure everything you have this will not do any harm to your system.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
```

Comment: Unknown option: a