# Upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 and LOSE everything

Tags: upgrade, updates

There are a couples of questions about upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 and keeping data/customizations etc. I want to do the exact opposite of that. That is, achieving the same result as in overwriting my current partition via booting and installing from a live cd. I am just wondering if, for convenience, it is possible to do so within my current installation(18.04).

Thanks.

EDIT: Just to clarify, my endgoal is to have clean Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: You can always format the partition and install. Or just [reset Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591167/resetting-ubuntu-to-factory-settings).

Comment: @Kulfy If I understand correctly both methods would require a live cd, correct?

Comment: If you're re-installing Ubuntu, yes. But if you're resetting Ubuntu using packages such resetter, you won't need live CD/USB.

Comment: @Kulfy So I have to use resetter and then upgrade you say. No other way to do it without a USB?

Comment: AFAIK, no. I'm not sure if answers on [How can I install Ubuntu without CD and USB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484434/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-cd-and-usb) still work.

Comment: Do you want to keep using 18.04, but as a clean install or use 20.04?

Comment: @crip659 Ubuntu 20.04. But without keeping anything from my current 18.04 installation, files, apps, repos, nothing. I want it to look like you took an empty disk(or partition in my case) and just installed Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Best way is to format drive before installing 20.04.  This clears everything.  If wanting to use upgrade path, then probably the resetter package(unknown) or manually remove everything you have installed(PIA).

Comment: @crisp659 Sorry but what is PIA?

Comment: Pain in the a's.  'stands for second s.  Keeping it kind of family friendly.

Comment: @pLumo Not really because I was looking for options during upgrading but it seems that's not possible. So I may as well use any of the methods mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

For whoever stumble upon this, I couldn't find a way to do it with upgrade so I did it with a liveUSB. The nice thing is that it automatically detects the Ubuntu partition and gives you the option to install there.