# Wipe everything from Ubuntu 22.04 except for the OS

Tags: server, 22.04, reset

I was wondering if it is possible to wipe an Ubuntu Server (22.04) expect for the operating system. I want to uninstall all software and files but not Ubuntu itself, similar to a factory reset on a phone.
For some more insight: A Galaxy (https://galaxyproject.github.io/) server was installed on the Ubuntu server by using git. This Galaxy server uses SQLite as the database and a built-in HTTP server. The server has to be deleted in order to manually install a new Galaxy server through Ansible.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resetting Ubuntu to factory settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591167/resetting-ubuntu-to-factory-settings). The lack of proper management and maintenance tools is indeed one disadvantage to using unpackaged software. Consider installing such software into an LXD container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to really "reset" is a fresh install, erasing and reformatting the disk.

All the rest involves manual cleanup, i.e. removing the software and configuration files. When using the APT system, an `apt purge` will also remove residual config. When using third party installation procedures, you are on your own: there might be an official "uninstallation" procedure, which you should attempt first before falling back on manual file deletion.