# Is it possible to factory reset my Ubuntu Server?

Tags: command-line, server, ssh, reset

The server is a physical server, so I have access to it, I could install Ubuntu via usb, but that would require me to bring a monitor to the other room, and access the hdmi port on the Gpu, which is very difficult, because the server is heavy and it has to be removed from its place. Can I somehow get a new install of ubuntu server running from ssh?

Comment: I think you need this: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall

Comment: i'm assuming your server doesn't have IDRAC or IPMI on it.  If it did, then you could do a 'console driven' reinstall - PXE boot to a PXE server, get Ubuntu ISO installed, do everything via the console - but unfortunately no, you can't do an SSH-driven installation remotely unless you have the installer set up and remote console access already.  Any reason you can't go to the server room and do the installation in place rather than remove the server from its rack?

Comment: Probably not helpful in the situation you're in, but when I set up servers (without mgt console access) I usually create a small rescue partition with a minimally functional Ubuntu. I can then reboot into that in the unlikely case the real system needs offline maintenance (e.g. fix issues on the root filesystem). I've done full rebuilds from the rescue partition using `debootstrap`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resetting Ubuntu to factory settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591167/resetting-ubuntu-to-factory-settings)