# Can't login even with password Linux ubuntu

Tags: login

I can't log on, it lets me type my password in and almost logs in but then goes back to the login screen. Can't even login on the guest account. I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> but it tells me my login is wrong even though I know it isn't.

Ubuntu 14.04.3

Comment: Please edit your question to include Ubuntu Version, Graphic hardware and installed driver

Comment: Honestly am not sure what graphic hardware is or what you mean by installed driver but I'll add my version

Comment: At the Ctrl+Alt+F2 prompt, make sure your are using your *login name* (usually all lower-case, with no whitespace) not your "full name" (which is what is usually displayed on the GUI login screen)

Comment: @ShauneyRhysThomas what had you done wrong?

Comment: @Tim In some extreme cases a lack of certain graphics driver components could lead to this bug

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I reset a lost password (using recovery mode requires me to type the password)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/121698/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-password-using-recovery-mode-requires-me-to-type-the-pass)

Answer (score 2):

You may need to change your password, or you may have the wrong username (does happen!).

First restart, then the moment the BIOS screen goes, press and hold <kbd>Left Shift</kbd>. This will open the GBUB menu.

From there, chose Advanced options for Ubuntu and then "Ubuntu with Linux 3.16.0-**-generic (recovery mode). If the numbers are different, don't worry. Just make sure it is recovery mode.

[image]
[image]

Then select "Drop to root shell prompt":

[image]

Next run the command `ls /home`. That will give you a list of usernames - check that yours is in that list (mine is `tim`).

[image]

If it is, then we will see if we can login from here. Type the following, followed by enter:

```
sudo login <username>
```

replace `<username>` with the username we just checked is correct. It will ask you for your username, like this:

[image]

If you get it correct, you should see a prompt that says "`User@Computer-Name:~$`". If the password is wrong, it will show "Login incorrect".

[image]
[image]

If your login is incorrect, we need to change it. [That's pretty simple](https://askubuntu.com/questions/423942/change-password-on-root-user-and-user-account).

First, mount your file system:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

then just use this command:

```
sudo passwd <username>
```

and change `username` out for your username.

It will ask you for a password twice - make sure to enter the same one both times.

[image]