# login issues after xubuntu 15.10 upgrade

Tags: xubuntu, login, 15.10

not so recently had my laptop ask for ubuntu to do an upgrade. now when I try to open it it goes through a xubuntu screen then back to what looks like a dos prompt asking for login and then password. I don't remember it asking for any info during the upgrade and i never used a login before but now i've been locked out of my pc for months. I've tried everything i can think of! somebody help this idiot get my pc back. And no this is not a dup of the one whose unity isnt working because this has nothing to do with unity. I cant even get to unity because the computer gets stuck at login. One person suggested that whatever I set it as when I first loaded ubuntu years ago is what it is. Great! except I have no idea what that would be and I have tried every possible combination of login and password combos I can think of. Since I've been doing this for 3 or 4 months Ive tried A LOT of combos. And on top of that when I type the password it appears to enter no character, data, on and on. So I dont even know if it is even working there.

Comment: since nobody else helped me I finally did it myself. If you have this similar issue look up how to change the GBUB menu. This may have been out of date as quite a few of the menu screens were different on mine but eventually I learned to get into the root menu and was able to load and run assword. And no that's not a misspelling or typo. Took a long time to run but it worked for me!!!!! http://askubuntu.com/questions/688222/cant-login-even-with-password-linux-ubuntu?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Great, may you write the answer in detail?