# Authentication fails after turning off login password

Tags: 16.04, login, password

Good day!

Ubuntu 16.04 runs on a laptop. It used to have a login password, i turned it off just now.

Now the system does not accept the sudo password anymore... I cannot unlock user account, terminal does not accept sudo password which worked fine prior to turning the login password off.

Enter does not work either.

Am i missing something? Thanks for your help in advance!

All the best, 
Hardovic

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/423942/change-password-on-root-user-and-user-account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this help page about recovering a lost password.

With that you can also create new users on the command line :

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword

After you manage to get a root shell on your own hard disk, you can do for example :

```
adduser mynewuser
adduser mynewuser sudo
```

Which adds a new user called "mynewuser", and then, with the second line, makes the new user part of group "sudo", which means giving the new user sudo rights.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It turned out i could just set a new password by using $ passwd in terminal. I was then asked by the shell to type in and repeat a new passsword. It worked for unlocking my user account and sudo commands afterwards.