# Encrypted user home page recovery

Tags: ssh, login, password, encryption, ecryptfs

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 version. I unfortunately lost access to my root user. I managed to login to other users. But as there is important data in it I would like to recover it.

I have tried many methods.

Ultimately used the command :-

```
ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase /home/username/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase
```

(**I don't know the passphrase**). 
As of now, there is no password for the root user which is unable to access(I removed the password somehow as a part of my recovery mission :P). However when I try to unwrap the passphrase, the login password is asking as usual, to which I have nothing to enter. Even I have tried entering the old password of root user. That also failed. How can I recover my data without using password?

This is the error I am getting when I enter old password, and it seems the error is simply password is incorrect.

```
Error: Unwrapping passphrase failed [-5]
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to login via the [recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) and setup a [new password](https://askubuntu.com/a/424039/566421) for the user?

Comment: I have tried the same. But not working. It is not showing any error.